# Jackson JsonTypeInfo for contents of HashMap<String, Object>

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization, json-deserialization

I have a JSON file (that I have no control over) that looks like this:

```
{
  "some-identifier": {
    "@class": "some-prefix.ClassA",
    "<classA-property1>": "value1",
    "<classA-property2>": "value2",
  },
  "some-other-identifier": {
    "@class": "some-other-prefix.ClassB",
    "<classB-property1>": <... possibly nested objects ...>
  },
  <...>
}
```

(The classA-properties and classB-properties are the actual names of the members of ClassA and ClassB respectively.)

I would like to deserialize this into a HashMap (mapping each identifier to the actual object) and I want to use a custom TypeIdResolver to determine the actual class to be instantiated (which I can determine from the prefix and class name). The objects themselves should then be deserialized using the default deserializer.

After a lot of searching I couldn't make this work. I need some way to annotate the HashMap in order to set JsonTypeInfo and JsonTypeIdResolver for its content. All examples I've seen so far have those annotations on a base type that all subclasses extend from. However, in my case, there is no common parent class for the classes contained in the JSON (except Object of course). I thought about annotating Object itself with a mixin, but even then this would break default deserialization for the contained objects since it would then expect an @class property on all child objects.

Is there a solution for this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can accomplish this by enabling the default type information for the object mapper like this:

```
new ObjectMapper().enableDefaultTyping(
        ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.JAVA_LANG_OBJECT,
        JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY);
```

Here is a complete example:

```
public class JacksonDefaultTypeInfo {
    static class Bean1 {
        public String value;

        Bean1() {}

        public Bean1(final String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Bean1{" +
                    "value='" + value + '\'' +
                    '}';
        }
    }

    static class Bean2 {
        public int number;

        Bean2() {}

        Bean2(final int number) {
            this.number = number;
        }


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        final Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("bean1", new Bean1("string"));
        map.put("bean2", new Bean2(123));

        final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper()
                .enableDefaultTyping(
                        ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.JAVA_LANG_OBJECT,
                        JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY);
        final String json = objectMapper
                .writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter()
                .writeValueAsString(map);

        System.out.println(json);
        final Map<String, Object> result = objectMapper.readValue(
                json,
                new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {});
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{
  "bean1" : {
    "@class" : "stackoverflow.JacksonDefaultTypeInfo$Bean1",
    "value" : "string"
  },
  "bean2" : {
    "@class" : "stackoverflow.JacksonDefaultTypeInfo$Bean2",
    "number" : 123
  }
}
{bean1=Bean1{value='string'}, bean2=Bean2{number=123}}
```

Comment: Enable default typing is unsafe, see [On Jackson CVEs: Don’t Panic — Here is what you need to know](https://medium.com/@cowtowncoder/on-jackson-cves-dont-panic-here-is-what-you-need-to-know-54cd0d6e8062)